# How to upload photos on twitter in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to upload photos on twitter in iPhone & i am used SOAuthentication engine & MSTwitterengine so please give me any link or examples to upload photos on twitter....

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code i used. Also have a look at [here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/02/23/adding-twitpic-to-your-application/)

```
-(void)postToTwitter:(NSString*)userN stringPass:(NSString *)Pwd
{

NSMutableData *webData;
// create the URL
NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitpic.com/api/uploadAndPost"];

// create the connection
NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:postURL
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:30.0];

// change type to POST (default is GET)
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];



// create data
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

NSString *consumer_token=@"";
NSString *consumer_secret=@"";
NSString *oauth_token=@"";
NSString *oauth_secret=@"";
NSString *api_key=@"";

NSString *message = @"Sample message posted";


// just some random text that will never occur in the body
NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";
// header value
NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];
// set header
[postRequest addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// username part
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[userN dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// password part
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[Pwd dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// api_key
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[api_key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// consumer_token
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"consumer_token\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[consumer_token dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// consumer_secret
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"consumer_secret\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[consumer_secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//oauth_token
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oauth_token\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[oauth_token dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//oauth_secret
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oauth_secret\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[oauth_secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// message part
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"message\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// media part
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media\"; filename=\"sampleme.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sampleme.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 90);

// add it to body
[postBody appendData:imageData];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// final boundary
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// add body to post
[postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

NSLog(@"%@",imageData);
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection )
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSLog(@"success");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}

}
```

Comment: ONce authenticated with twitter, just code it there to post your message and photo

Comment: @Prasanna Venkatesh . Your code really helped me a lot. But I don't know how to get data in my server with php. If you know it, share me please.

Comment: @Prasanna Venkatesh. The media part to get is in terms of $_FILES['media'].

Comment: @anna, Forgive me. What you want to do?

Comment: @Prasanna Venkatesh, when the url request is received by server, the server will deal with the data. BTW, the server side is done myself. So i'd like to get the data and deal with them . But I don't know how to get them.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend using [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/). It's easy to send anything to a variety of services, including Twitter.

Comment: sharekit not working any more its useless now, before 6 month its ok but now their api is too old and every social media has modified their api so its useless now

Comment: I still use it and it works fine. You might want to read their documentation.