# send a picture with an account information like accountID(ios)

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlrequest, content-disposition

I want to send a picture with an account information like an accountID. Now I have done with sending a picture, but failed to send an accountID, because I'm litte familiar with NSURLRequest.setHttpBody. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure where is the picture sent and know well the API provided by the server(e.g. facebook). Then add all the related information such as your accountID in the HTTPBody. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422835/how-to-upload-photos-on-twitter-in-iphone) maybe helpful, good luck!